# Clone whole partition or hard drive to a sparse file

Tags: dd, cloning, sparse-files

I like to clone a whole partition or a whole hard drive onto a larger external disk but like to create a sparse file. I often use `dd` for cloning, but it doesn't support sparse files. As a workaround I used something like:

```
cp --sparse=always <(dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=8M) /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

However this is a little too tricky for my taste and doesn't allow me to resume the process if aborted. It is funny that there is a NTFS tool for this (`ntfsclone`) but no such tool exists for the native file systems of Linux (EXT2-4).

Is there some better tool for this, e.g. a `dd` variant with sparse support? 
I do not look for some proprietary software for disk backups but simply want to make a sparse clone copy which I can mount as loop device if required.

Comment: +1 for creative use of `cp`, it never occurred to me that you could sparse-copy a disk image. I always just compressed them if I needed to save space. Now why is that in a question not an answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want [`dd_rescue`](http://man.cx/dd_rescue).

```
dd_rescue -a -b 8M /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

---

The copy may be interrupted at any time by <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, showing the current position. This value can be used, when restarting by adding `-s` and the position to the original command, e.g.

```
dd_rescue -a -b 8M -s 42000k /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

---

Even easier would be to specify a third file name, which acts as a log file. On restart `dd_rescue` will read that log file and pick up where it left off.

Comment: Great! The manual says "If the copying process is interrupted by the user it is possible to continue at any position later." and "-a  spArse file writing (default=no)". Exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: Looking for `dd_rescue` online I found out that there is also a different tool called [`ddrescue`](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue) (without the underscore) which was developed independently from `dd_rescue` but seems to do basically the same. I just mention that here as a general FYI.

Comment: Yeah, `dd_rescue` and `ddrescue` aren't the same thing.  Theoretically they do the same job, but generally I've had better luck with the older/original `dd_rescue`.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, you can stop the copy at any time with Ctrl-C.  It will show you your current position, and you can use that value to restart by adding `-s` and the position to the original command.  (So it would look like `dd_rescue -a -b 8M -s 42000k /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw`.)

Comment: @Steven Pritchard: No need to remember the position. Specify a third filename, which will be the logfile, and on restart it'll read that and pick up where it left off.

Comment: Rather strange I get almost twice as fast image creation with ddrescue compared to dd, with increase blocksize in dd! (FYI: Debian package name gddrescue, but executable and manual is still ddrescue, took me some time to get that right!)

Comment: Just fyi, the ddrescue tool wants the -S option for sparse output, as opposed to -a with dd_rescue

Answer (score 22):

Just for completeness the call for [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html). The `--sparse` or `-S` flag allows the destination to be written sparsely:

```
$ ddrescue -S -b8M /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

Or with long option:

```
$ ddrescue --sparse --block-size 8M /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

Or if you prefer [MiBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte):

```
$ ddrescue -S -b8Mi /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

To allow the rescue to be interrupted and resumed, you can also make use of a logfile:

```
$ ddrescue -S -b8Mi /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw ~/sda1.rescue.log
```

Note that GNU `ddrescue` and `dd_rescue` are different programs. But GNU `ddrescue` seems to be more widespread. For example it is already packaged with [GRML](http://grml.org/).

Comment: Does there need to be any special treatment of the image when restoring, can you provide the command used to restore a ddrescue?

Comment: In theory the storage medium you're using for the rescue is supposed to be more reliable, so you can typically just use dd to write to the replacement disk: `dd if=sda1.raw of=/dev/sdb1`. However, to use ddrescue for the restore, you just change the source/destination you used for the rescue to the new source/destination, preferably with a new log file. If possible (often not), you can of course use ddrescue to copy data *directly* from the bad source disk to a replacement disk.

Answer (score 3):

There was a [patch offered](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg11795.html) in 2007 to provide sparse file support in GNU dd, but it looks to have not made it into coreutils (at least not as of 8.4). I doubt dd has changed too much since then, the patch might apply against the current version without a lot of work.

I'm also really impressed by the creative use of `cp` in your question, and it got me on the track of using it to accomplish resuming (here resuming from ~80M into the source):

```
cp --sparse=always \
  <(dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=8M skip=10) /dev/stdout \
  | dd bs=8M seek=10 of=/mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

Edit: scratch that. The second `dd` would of course be seeking to the wrong position in the output file, since it's not the same length as the input.

Comment: As is the case with bhinesley's answer, it would be best to log dd's progress for accurate resuming. If you were to use this approach for both the first run and resumes, and log both parallel dd's independently, then you could know how far into the output to seek. If I have time I'll try to work this up.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the patch. I was starting to think about programming something like it by myself :-) Sparse files can't be pipped so your code won't work.

Comment: Yup, I just discovered that myself. Oh well, it was fun finding crazy new uses of `cp` - thanks!

Comment: dd commit at 2012: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=4e776faa8482ae630d2ea9bc767298e664f07ba9 "dd: add support for the conv=sparse option" ("(iwrite): Convert a write of a NUL block to a seek if requested.")

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question, and `dd` developers added support for sparse files [over a decade ago](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=4e776faa8482ae630d2ea9bc767298e664f07ba9) (as was pointed out by osgx in a comment above). Nowadays you can simply run:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mount/external/backup/sda1.raw bs=8M conv=sparse status=progress
```

Depending on how fragmented your data is, you might also be able to achieve a smaller file by specifying a smaller block size value.

Unlike `dd_rescue`, `ddrescue`, `qemu-img` or `rsync`, `dd` is typically installed by default on GNU/Linux systems (and easier to use than `cp --sparse=always $(dd ...`, which may make it a more desirable option.

If you cancel the `dd` command, you will get something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=sda1.raw bs=512 conv=sparse status=progress
10724033024 bytes (11 GB, 10 GiB) copied, 538 s, 19.9 MB/s^C
20967649+0 records in
20967648+0 records out
10735435776 bytes (11 GB, 10 GiB) copied, 539.375 s, 19.9 MB/s
```

You can later use the smaller value to resume by adding the `seek=` and `skip=` arguments, like so:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=sda1.raw bs=512 conv=sparse status=progress seek=20967648 skip=20967648
```

You could also obtain the value via something like:

```
ls -l --block-size=512 sda1.raw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20967648 Nov 10 21:00 sda1.raw
```

Comment: simple `cp --sparse=always /dev/disk disk.img` should work, without involving `<(dd ...)` not sure why that was done. `dd conv=sparse` is useful if you want to specify the block size. Note that alignment matters as well, so `bs=8M` could leave a 15M sequence of zeroes as non-sparse if it's not aligned to 8M boundary. For large blocksizes (or when reading from a pipe) you should also add `iflag=fullblock`.

Comment: `conv=sparse` is good. @frostschutz `dd bs=8M` was used for speed improvements on large data. I see now that `conv=sparse` only works with completly empty output blocks (`obs`), so `dd conv=sparse ibs=8M obs=512` or similar would be a better way.  In general filesystem-aware cloning tools like `ntfsclone` or `e2image` would be preferable I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my 2 cents. Another way to create a sparse file from a raw disk is with [qemu-img](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img) using something like:

```bsh
qemu-img convert -f raw /dev/sda /tmp/sda.raw
```

You can use this on a single partition as well. Also, you have the option to convert the raw disk/partition to any other format that qemu-img supports (QCOW2, VHD[x], vmdk, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
cp --sparse=always /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/).  For example:

```
rsync -SP --copy-devices /dev/sda1 /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw
```

Explanation:

- `-S`/`--sparse` to skip sparse blocks on write
- `-P`/`--partial --progress` to show progress and keep partially transferred files
- `--copy-devices` to copy device contents<sup>1</sup>

You can add `--append` to resume an interrupted copy (or `--append-verify` to confirm the checksum over both new and old data matches).

###### Footnotes

1. The `--copy-devices` option is provided by [copy-devices.diff](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync-patches.git;a=blob;f=copy-devices.diff) from rsync-patches, so it may not be present on some systems.  It is included by [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/494313), [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/728227), [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/509335) (until 3.2.0-1, see [Bug 992215](https://bugs.debian.org/992215)), and likely others.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the OP is specifically looking to clone an EXT 2/3/4 filesystem. There is a tool to do just exactly this called `e2image`. And can be used like so:

```
e2image -rap <source> <dest>
```

This will create a sparse file on filesystems that support sparse files and will create a raw filesystem image, but there are other options for other formats (eg. QCOW2).

The problem with using `dd` or `dd_rescue` to sparsely copy filesystems is that they aren't that smart. So if you have a filesystem that has been in use for a long time, its likely that you have many free blocks that are not zero-filled. These will get copied to the image file unnecessarily. So you could end up with an image the size of the filesystem even though `df` shows, say, 50% utilization. This can be worked around by using TRIM or zero-filling free blocks before using these commands. Or you could just use e2image and not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this doesn't work for the reasons described in the comments, I'm leaving it here for reference.

Monitor the statistics of dd by using kill -USR1:

```
$ cp --sparse=always <(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=8M) \
    /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw&
$ watch kill -USR1 `pidof -s /bin/dd`
```

Resume by using skip/seek:

```
$ i_bytes= # get from the last dd statistic
$ o_bytes=`du -b /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw | cut -f 1`   
$ cp --sparse=always <(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=8M skip=$i_bytes \
    seek=$o_bytes) /mount/external/backup/sda1.raw&
$ watch kill -USR1 `pidof -s /bin/dd`
```

Without $i_bytes it would be more difficult to resume. It's probably easiest to log the dd statistics to a file in case the machine crashes or whatever.

Comment: The second `cp` will just overwrite the existing file, wouldn't it? I know the `skip` and other options of `dd`. The issue is the `cp` part.

Comment: Hm, yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

There are [**xfsdump**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfsdump.8.html) and [**xfsrestore**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfsrestore.8.html) for XFS which has been a native Linux filesystem for quite a long time.