# How to clone RFS on NAND on ARM Chip?

Tags: debian, arm, clonezilla

I have a Cm-FX6 ARM chip on which there is 8GB onboard NAND which I use as the root filesystem, running Debian 6. 
How do I clone the root filesystem image? 
Is it possible to use Clonezilla to do so?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clonezilla isn't available for ARM processors (at least not as a bootable image from the main download site), and isn't packaged for Debian 6.

In Debian 6 on ARM you can clone your filesystem using [`partimage`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/partimage), [`dd_rescue`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ddrescue) or [`ddrescue`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gddrescue). The latter two are described in [Clone whole partition or hard drive to a sparse file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17087/clone-whole-partition-or-hard-drive-to-a-sparse-file/17331#17331).